# Unable to boot from USB installer (17-inch, 2.66GHz MacBook Pro (MB604LL/A)

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, usb, startup, install

I have an old 2009 macbook pro that had problems with hard drive. I changed it to new SSD (also updated ram to 2x4gb 1066MHz DDR3 SDRAM PC3-8500S), and created bootable USB in windows with TransMac software. However my macbook will not boot from the usb, only shows up white screen with ?-folder.

I have tried to search information if it is even possible to start the installer from usb in this old laptop, but have not found any confirmation. Is there difference on what osx I create the boot usb, should it be 10.5 leopard as that is the os the laptop has had when new, or can I install the newest os that this computer supports (El Capitan)?

Comment: The procedure for using a PC to download and create a USB flash drive installer for Lion through Sierra has be answered. See [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/309399/how-can-i-download-an-older-version-of-os-x-macos/460961#460961). I am going to close this question as a duplicate. If you have additional problems, edit your question, add the problems, then ask for the question to be reopened. Or, post a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Your Early 2009 MBP should be able to boot from an external drive to any OS between Leopard (10.5.6) and El Capitan (10.11), all things being good. But USB2 is going to be slow.

First, we need to find out if the Windows TransMac software has correctly made a bootable Mac volume. At startup, hold the Alt/Option key. You should be offered an interface showing available drives to choose. Is it listed?

Do you have any friends with Macs that you could test the USB drive? Or at least prepare an installer there?

Do you still have the old hard drive? It might be worthwhile spending a very small sum on a [USB to SATA cable](https://www.amazon.co.uk/s?k=usb%20to%20SATA%20cable&crid=NJPDMKU1MTRS&sprefix=usb%20to%20sata%20cable%2Caps%2C119&ref=nb_sb_noss_1), so that you can boot from that, which will give you some capability, at least, until you get the SSD sorted.

Comment: Thanks for quick help, Holding down only the alt/option key, or holding down alt+cmd+r neither one does nothing, only shows up the question mark folder. Unfortunately I do not have the old hard drive available any more. I will be able to test the usb with my friends macbook and will post an update if I am able to create installer that way.